# JS onclick añade elemento fieldset indeseado (era PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

Tengo el siguiente código. Es un selector de prendas con tipo, talle, color y sexo. Cuando uno da click en `+`
(añadir línea) de selección de prendas crea un nuevo `fieldset` selector. El nuevo `fieldset` se añade correctamente.
Sin embargo mirando el `console.log()` hay una y solo una etiqueta `<fieldset>` indeseada y no tengo idea de por qué.

```
... mas código ...
    <form method="post" action="presupuesto_nuevo.php">
        <fieldset>
            <p>Cliente: <?=lista_clientes("select"); ?> </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset name="prendas_fieldset" id="prendas_fieldset">
            <fieldset name="selector_nueva_linea">
                <label for="agregar_prenda">Prendas </label>
                <input type='button' name='agregar_prenda' value='+' id='btn_selector_prendas'>
            </fieldset>
            <?=$prendas_fieldset;?>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
        let contador = 0;
        /* esta constante es igual a $prendas_fieldset con los cambios de \n y entrecomillado para JS */
        const js_prendas_fieldset = "<?=$prendas_fieldset_js;?>";

        document.getElementById('btn_selector_prendas').onclick = function () {
            container = document.getElementById('prendas_fieldset');
            nuevo_fieldset = document.createElement('fieldset');
            nuevo_fieldset.innerHTML = js_prendas_fieldset;
            container.appendChild(nuevo_fieldset);
            contador++;
            console.log(container.innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
    ... mas código ...
```

Y esta es la salida de `console.log()`:

```
    <fieldset name="selector_nueva_linea">
        <label for="agregar_prenda">Prendas </label>
        <input type="button" name="agregar_prenda" value="+" id="btn_selector_prendas">
    </fieldset>
        <fieldset name="linea_prendas">
        <!-- código de línea que se carga por defecto -->
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> <!-- este es indeseado -->
        <fieldset name="linea_prendas">
                <!-- código de la nueva línea que es igual a la por defecto -->
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset> <!-- y la etiqueta de cierre del indeseado -->
```

Graceas!

**Edición: añadir contenido de variable `$prendas_fieldset_js`:**

```
/** fieldset selector de prendas */
$prendas_fieldset = "           <fieldset name=\"linea_prendas\">
                <label for=\"tipo_prenda[]\">Tipo: </label>
                $select_tipos_prenda
                <label for=\"color_prenda[]\">Color: </label>
                $select_colores_prenda
                <label for=\"talle_prenda[]\">Talle: </label>
                $select_talles_prenda
                <label for=\"sexo_prenda[]\">Sexo: </label>
                $select_sexos_prenda
                <label for=\"cantidad_prenda[]\">Cantidad: </label>
                $input_cantidad
            </fieldset>\n";

$prendas_fieldset_js = str_replace('<fieldset name=\"linea_prendas\">', "", $prendas_fieldset);
$prendas_fieldset_js = str_replace('</fieldset>', "", $prendas_fieldset_js);
$prendas_fieldset_js = str_replace('"', "'", $prendas_fieldset_js);
$prendas_fieldset_js = str_replace("\n", "", $prendas_fieldset_js); /* no es la forma ortodoxa, en fin... */
```

Que da como resultado:

```
const js_prendas_fieldset = "           <fieldset name='linea_prendas'>
    <label for='tipo_prenda[]'>Tipo: </label>
    <select name='tipo_prenda[]'>
        <option value='0'>selecionar</option>
        <option value='1'>Remera algodón 20/1 cuello redondo</option>
        <option value='2'>Remera algodón 20/1 cuello v</option>
        <option value='3'>Tela algodón 20/1</option>
    </select>
    <label for='color_prenda[]'>Color: </label>
    <select name='tipo_prenda[]'>
        <option value='0'>selecionar</option>
        <option value='3'>Amarillo</option>
        <option value='4'>Azul francia</option>
        <option value='10'>Azul oscuro</option>
        <option value='1'>Blanco</option>
        <option value='11'>Melange</option>
        <option value='2'>Negro</option>
        <option value='6'>Rojo</option>
        <option value='5'>Verde brasil</option>
    </select>
    <label for='talle_prenda[]'>Talle: </label>
    <select name='talle_prenda[]'>
        <option value='0'>selecionar</option>
        <option value='1'>S (1)</option>
        <option value='2'>M (2)</option>
        <option value='3'>L (3)</option>
        <option value='4'>XL (4)</option>
        <option value='5'>XXL (5)</option>
        <option value='6'>XXXL (6)</option>
    </select>
    <label for='sexo_prenda[]'>Sexo: </label>
    <select name='sexo_prenda[]'>
        <option value='0'>selecionar</option>
        <option value='1'>hombre</option>
        <option value='2'>mujer</option>
    </select>
    <label for='cantidad_prenda[]'>Cantidad: </label>
    <input type='text' name='cantidad_prenda[]' class='lng_s'>          ";
```

Comment: He probado tu código y hace lo esperado, exactamente que contiene tu variable `$prendas_fieldset_js;`?

Comment: @RicardoAlvarado añadí el contenido de la variable en una edición de la pregunta

Comment: Deberías verificar que `$prendas_fieldset_js` sea válido, he hecho una simulación rápida con tu código php para generarlo y no veo cierres de algunas etiquetas

Comment: @RicardoAlvarado todo el código es válido. No hay ninguna clase de error/aviso ni de PHP, ni HTML ni JS. Todo el código es válido y todas las etiquetas se cierran. Lo [validé](https://validator.w3.org) y solo hay avisos por los corchetes. Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: @RicardoAlvarado, Lo resolví. No era JS, era PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema venía así.

Esta línea de `PHP`:

`$prendas_fieldset_js = str_replace('<fieldset name=\"linea_prendas\">', "", $prendas_fieldset);`

tiene escapadas las comillas dobles. En ese momento las comillas ya estaban escapadas. Entonces no hacía el reemplazo porque usé las comillas simples (y eso toma la cadena literal). La línea debe quedar así:

`$prendas_fieldset_js = str_replace('<fieldset name="linea_prendas">', "", $prendas_fieldset);`

Eso resuelve el problema y de hecho eso me llevó a poner mal las etiquetas (voy a añadir PHP).